# How Disable href

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I want to disable the `<a class="fancybox" href="addrfq.php?pn=' . $row["counter"] . '"></a>` if the quantity in purchase_order reaches the total_quantity in purchase_request.

I have two tables: Purchase_request and Purchase_order. When quantity reaches its maximum quantity, I want to disable the HREF. How can I do that?

Purchase_Request

```
counter | total_quantity 

000004  |  3000  
000172  |  100  
000007  |  500  
000005  |  300
```

Purchase_Order

```
counter | quantity 

000004  |  2999  
000004  |  1
```

Pr.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");

    $result = $mysqli->query("
    select 
        a.counter,
        a.total_quantity, a.pr,
        a.total_quantity - b.quantity balance,
        b.quantity, b.unit, b.unit_cost,
        b.unit_cost * b.quantity total_amount,
        c.item_name
    from
        (select counter, pr,
        sum(total_quantity) total_quantity
        from purchase_request
        group by counter) a 
    left outer join
        (select counter, unit, unit_cost,
        sum(quantity) quantity
        from purchase_order 
        group by counter) b 
    on a.counter= b.counter
    inner join
        (select counter, item_name
        from app 
        group by counter) c 
    on a.counter= c.counter
    group by a.counter
    order by a.pr
    ");
    echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter" style="text-transform:uppercase;" border="1px">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        </thead>';
        echo'<tbody>';
    $i=1;   
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$i++.'</td>
            <td align="center"><a class="fancybox" href="addrfq.php?pn=' . $row["counter"] . '"><img src="images/add.png" border="0" width="10" height="10" title="Add Purchase Order"></a></td>
            <td>'.$row['counter'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['pr'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['unit'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['unit_cost'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['total_quantity'].'</td>
            <td>'. number_format($row['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',') .'</td>
            <td>'.$row['balance'].'</td>
        </tr>';
       }
    echo "</tbody></table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if ($row['quantity'] < $row['total_quantity']) {
    echo "<a href='abc.php'>Link</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Disabled link</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just think about it :p

```
if($row['quantity']<$row['total_quantity'])
{  
    echo "<a href='whatever.php'>Link example</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='#'>No sir</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not in the 'addrfq.php' file, before adding / processing a query, you check to see if they reached the max.  If they have not reached the max, then proceed to process query.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<td align="center"><a class="fancybox" href="addrfq.php?pn=' . $row["counter"] . '"><img src="images/add.png" border="0" width="10" height="10" title="Add Purchase Order"></a></td>
```

To:

```
<td align="center"><a class="fancybox" href="' . ($i < $row['total_quantity'] ? 'addrfq.php?pn=' . $row["counter"] : 'javascript:void(0)') . '"><img src="images/add.png" border="0" width="10" height="10" title="Add Purchase Order"></a></td>
```